# how can I get the the li specific to a ul if i have more than one ul and all the li have same classname

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want all the `li` in each `ul` arranged in this form 0px,200px,400px,etc.. depending on the number of `li` inside that specific `ul`. My codes joins it up this way 0px,200px,400px,600px,800px,notice from 600px the `li` is in another `ul` i want it also starting from 0px,200px in that format. How can I achieve this?

```js
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
var art = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
var child = [],
  slideWidth = 200;



for (var i = 0; i < art.length; i++) {
  art[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    getslide(event)
  })
}

function getslide(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    let elem = event.target.getAttribute('data');
    if (slide[i].getAttribute('data') != null && slide[i].getAttribute('data') == elem) {
      console.log(slide[i].style.left = slideWidth * i + 'px);
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<article data=0>
  <button class="btn2">></button>
  <button class="btn1">
                            <</button>
  <h5 class="pricin">N20,000</h5>
  <ul class="slider">
    <li class="slide" data=0>
      <img src="image-2.jpeg" alt="">
    </li>

    <li class="slide" data=0>
      <img src="image-4.jpeg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" data=0>
      <img src="summer.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
<article data=1>
  <button class="btn2">></button>
  <button class="btn1">
                            <</button>
  <h5 class="pricin">N20,000</h5>
  <ul class="slider">
    <li class="slide" data=1>
      <img src="image-1.jpeg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" data=1>
      <img src="image-5.jpeg" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: I was not able to understand what exactly you want to be done. Also, can you please provide the initial idea, what has to be done with these lists. I think that there is a chance to have better approach to handle your problem.

Comment: @Rado here is the idea, I am trying to create an image slider for  both ul, so I need the li in each ul to be arranged on a straight line to the left as 0px, 200px, 400px... With respect to the numbers of li in that particular ul..

Answer (score 2):

Can you edit the HTML at all? I would suggest giving them a unique ID or giving them another class. Elements can have multiple classes so are not limited to just one.

You could also attempt to use parent or child selectors but you dont seem to have any unique identifiers so will be difficult to do.

Comment: each ul is an image slider so they need to look alike, I am trying to avoid hard coding every time a new ul will be added dynamically

Answer (score 2):

You can use different id attributes on ul and use

```
var slide = document.querySelectorAll("#myId > .slide")
```

You can also use querySelectorAll on an element.

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myId")
var slide = slider.querySelectorAll(".slide")
```

you can always make something more or less specific by using combinations of selectors

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, probably missing css will bridge the gap, but here is a solution according to my understanding.

```
        var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
        var art = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
        var child = [],
          slideWidth = 200;

        for (var i = 0; i < art.length; i++) {
            art[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
                getslide(event)
            })
        }

        function getslide(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
                var slide = slider[i].getElementsByClassName('slide');
                for (var j = 0; j < slide.length; j++) {
                    let elem = event.target.getAttribute('data');
                    if (slide[j].getAttribute('data') != null && slide[j].getAttribute('data') == elem) {
                        console.log(slide[j].style.left = slideWidth * j + 'px');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've used two loops. First one is for the sliders and second one is for the slides inside that particular slider. Thats why I've declared `var slide` inside the first loop. Everytime the slider changes, the `j` variable will start from `0`. So your pixel count will start from `0`. Not a very elegant solution but it will work. Hope that helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks for your effort, I'll update the css right away